# Batch traverse subolders and rename files

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, directory, traversal

I would like to traverse a folder and all it's subfolders, keep a counter variable of the current file and rename it to $counter$ExistingFileName.
E.g.

```
$count = 1;  
foreach $file in $folder  
{  
  $file.name = $count + $file.name;  
  $count++;  
}
```

The person who can answer this will be my hero! :)
Btw I am using Windows 7.

Comment: That easy? I *can* answer this. :) But seriously, what exactly is the new name template? Is it like `file.ext` ==> `1file.ext`? or should it be `1$file.ext`? or maybe `00001file.ext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, while you are pondering over my questions in my comment to your post (or maybe still making your way back to this site to read them), here's my trial shot:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "rootdir=%~1"
IF "%rootdir%"=="" SET rootdir=.
SET cnt=0
FOR /R "%rootdir%" %%f IN (*) DO (
  SET /A cnt+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%f" "!cnt!%%~nxf"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

This will rename your files by simply prepending their names with numbers, like this:

```
1file.txt
2program.exe
...
```

If you like, you can have it this way:

```
00001file.txt
00002program.exe
```

For that you'll need to make two changes to the above script (highlighted in bold):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "rootdir=%~1"
IF "%rootdir%"=="" SET rootdir=.
SET cnt=10000
FOR /R "%rootdir%" %%f IN (*) DO (
  SET /A cnt+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%f" "!cnt:~1!%%~nxf"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer!  But when I paste this code in the console, I get a syntax error after the FOR, saying that "%%f" cannot be processed.

Comment: Not really sure I understand what you did. This is supposed to be a script, stored in a text file with the extension of `.bat` or `.cmd`. You then run the script. By the way, I forgot to add that it also accepts a parameter, which would be the root folder from where to start traversing.

Comment: Ok I pasted this into rename.bat.  Then from the console, I called rename.bat c:\test  and I also tried  rename.bat "c:\test", but get a syntax error :(

Comment: @Brent: That definitely puzzles me. Could you please remove the `@ECHO OFF` line or simply add `::` at its beginning, then run the script again *from the command window* and tell me which lines caused the errors?

Comment: C:\test>rename.bat c:\test\1  
  
C:\test>SET "rootdir=c:\test\1"  
  
C:\test>IF c:\test\1. == . SET rootdir=.  
  
C:\test>SET cnt=10000  
  
C:\test>FOR /R "c:\test\1" %f IN (*) DO (  
SET /A cnt+=1  
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion  
 RENAME %f !cnt:~1!%~nxf  
 ENDLOCAL  
)  
  
C:\test>(  
SET /A cnt+=1  
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion  
 RENAME c:\test\1\folder number 1\CD01\01 Track 1.mp3 !cnt:~1!01   Track 1.mp3  
 ENDLOCAL  
)  
Syntaxfehler.

Comment: @Brent: Ah, my bad, what a shame! The names are not enclosed in double quotes. Fixed now. Sorry.

Comment: ..one more question though:  If the folder name contains a space, I get a syntax error. E.g. rename.bat "c:\the test folder" leads to a syntax error:  C:\Users\Nils\Topics>SET "rootdir=C:\the test folder"
"test" cannot be processed syntactically.

Comment: Actually the easiest solution for me would be if you just put the batch file in a folder, run it and then it renames all files in that folder and sub folders accordingly. Another useful addition would be to exclude certain file extensions from both renaming and counting.

Comment: @Brent: The issue about spaces in the root folder name is fixed now, sorry again. This script actually can work like you have described, i.e. it will process the current folder if no parameter has been specified. It just that the batch file should be somewhere outside the folder tree you are going to process. The addition you've also mentioned is indeed a good one. But, mind you, it should be requested as a new question.

Comment: Thanks! Now the parameter works. As said, the best solution would be if I just put the batch file in the target folder and run it, but then it renames the batch file itself, and the first target file starts at 2. The workaround would be to set cnt=-1. It still renames the batch file itself, but that's ok. Cheers!

Comment: ... now since I only want to include mp3 files in the renaming and counting, I am just looking for an addition to do that ;)

Comment: That is quite simple (much simpler than *excluding* certain extensions). Just replace the `*` mask in the `FOR` loop with `*.mp3` and that's it. If you need to include more than one extension, list them like this: `*.mp3 *.wma *.ogg` (i.e. delimit the masks with spaces).

Answer (score 1):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set count=1
for /r .\folder %%f IN (*.*) do (
    ren "%%f" "!count!%%~nf%%~xf"
    set /a count=!count!+1)
```

Comment: I tried to paste this in the console, but got a syntax error! :(

Comment: Place it into a batch file and then run the batch file. Rename the .\folder to the folder on your HD you want to recurse into.

Comment: So if the folder is c:\test\1, how is the script supposed to look like? I was messing around with a few options, but always get syntax errors.

Comment: I placed the above script in a file call `r.bat`.  I created the folder c:\test\1, replaced `.\folder` with `c:\test\1` and was able to run the batch file successfully.  You **cannot** just past the above in the console because the `for` command is multi-line.